# SSISDB Size growing too much

Tags: ssis, maintenance-plan

I had set the RETENTION_WINDOW property to 5 and OPERATION_CLEANUP_ENABLED to true and SSIS maintenance job is running every day at night but SSIDB still growing too much now it is more than 110GB from 20GB. So I want to know is it good to set up a maintenance plan to Shrink SSISDB or is there any other approach I can apply to reduce size of ssisdb

Comment: What's the recovery model setting set to? For dev environments I usually change  the default Full mode to Simple + the SSIS Catalogue setting "Server-wide Default Logging Level" from Basic to Performance.

Comment: the recovery model is set to Simple and also the logging level is set to performance. do you have any maintenance plan for that I mean on weekly time